# What is this box that drops red bubbles when I try to get it?

Tags: nimbatus

In some planets, there are those boxes (like the one with the discrete blue arrow) and when I try to grab them, they throw some red bubbles.

I tried to bring it to the collector but nothing happened.

What should I do with them?[image]